Vuetify3 VSimpleTable upgrade to VTable do not work
v-simple-table has been renamed to v-table
Old code after rename v-simple-table to v-table do not work correctly,
v-data-table with same date work correctly.

Full page code
Example code for this problem
I tried to change the location of the component, data source and parent components.
template->v-app->v-main...

Follow the migration instructions mostly. What is the issue? You probably know how to navigate those 350 lines of code better than us.

There don't seem any issues from the example...

difference between examples from v2 and v3

V3
V2

Example on The simpler of the table components with CDN requires a additional template attribute with default slot  template v-slot:default
Before
<v-table theme="dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-left">
          Name {{desserts.length}}
        </th>
        <th class="text-left">
          Calories
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in desserts" :key="item.name">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</v-table>

After
<v-table theme="dark">
  <template v-slot:default>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-left">
          Name {{desserts.length}}
        </th>
        <th class="text-left">
          Calories
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in desserts" :key="item.name">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
</v-table>

Result

